# Expects parameter '@CustomerPhoto', which was not supplied

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I have this error during update of the customer table:

> Procedure or function 'Update_Customer' expects parameter '@CustomerPhoto', which was not supplied.

Stored procedure code :

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[Update_Customer]
    @CustomerID int output,
    @CustomerName nvarchar (50),
    @CustomerPhoto image,
    @CustomerEmail nvarchar(Max),
    @CustomerPhone1 nvarchar(12),
    @CustomerPhone2 nvarchar(12),
    @CustomerAddress nvarchar(Max),
    @CustomerFax nvarchar(12),
    @CustomerStatus bit,
    @CountryID int,
    @CityID int,
    @Notes nvarchar (Max),
    @ModifiedBy nvarchar (30)
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE CustomersTbl 
    SET CustomerID = @CustomerID,
        CustomerName = @CustomerName,
        CustomerPhoto = @CustomerPhoto,
        CustomerEmail = @CustomerEmail,
        CustomerPhone1 = @CustomerPhone1,
        CustomerPhone2 = @CustomerPhone2,
        CustomerAddress = @CustomerAddress,
        CustomerFax = @CustomerFax,
        CustomerStatus = @CustomerStatus,
        CountryID = @CountryID,
        CityID = @CityID,
        Notes = @Notes,
        ModifiedDate = GETDATE(),
        ModifiedBy = @ModifiedBy
    WHERE
        CustomerID = @CustomerID
END
```

Data layer class code :

```
Friend Function Update_Customer(ByVal CustomerID As String, ByVal CustomerName As String, ByVal CustomerEmail As String, ByVal CustomerPhone1 As String, ByVal CustomerPhone2 As String, ByVal CustomerAddress As String, ByVal CustomerFax As String, ByVal CustomerStatus As Boolean, ByVal CountryID As Integer, ByVal CityID As Integer, ByVal Notes As String, ByVal ModifiedBy As String) As String
    Dim retval As String

    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Update_Customer")

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerID", CustomerID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerName", CustomerName)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhoto", SqlDbType.Image).Value = photo
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerEmail", CustomerEmail)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhone1", CustomerPhone1)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhone2", CustomerPhone2)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerAddress", CustomerAddress)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerFax", CustomerFax)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerStatus", CustomerStatus)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryID", CountryID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", CityID)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Notes", Notes)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModifiedBy", ModifiedBy)

    retval = dm.executeNonQuery(cmd)

    Return retval
End Function
```

Business layer class code :

```
Public Function Update_Customer_WithOutPic(ByVal CustomerID As String, ByVal CustomerName As String, ByVal CustomerEmail As String, ByVal CustomerPhone1 As String, ByVal CustomerPhone2 As String, ByVal CustomerAddress As String, ByVal CustomerFax As String, ByVal CustomerStatus As Boolean, ByVal CountryID As Integer, ByVal CityID As Integer, ByVal Notes As String, ByVal ModifiedBy As String) As String
    Dim retval As String
    retval = p.Update_Customer_WithOutPic(CustomerID, CustomerName, CustomerEmail, CustomerPhone1, CustomerPhone2, CustomerAddress, CustomerFax, CustomerStatus, CountryID, CityID, Notes, ModifiedBy)
    Return retval
End Function
```

Update button code :

```
Dim retval As String = p.Update_Customer(txtCustomerCode.Text, txtCustomerName.Text, txtCustomerEmail.Text, txtCustomerPhone1.Text, txtCustomerPhone2.Text, txtCustomerAddress.Text, txtCustomerFax.Text, CheckBox2.Checked, ComboCustomerCountry.SelectedValue, ComboCustomerCity.SelectedValue, txtCustomernote.Text, FrmMain.LblUserID.Text)
```

Error :

> Procedure or function 'Update_Customer' expects parameter '@CustomerPhoto', which was not supplied.

Comment: **Error is clear** : You are not passing value for the parameter, `@CustomerPhoto`.

Comment: its here cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CustomerPhoto", SqlDbType.Image).Value = photo

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question is well-phrased and follows the rules of [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your title could use a little improvement, though. +1

Comment: You should not be combining `AddWithValue` with `SqlDbType`, are you shure you did not mean to do `cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustomerPhoto", SqlDbType.Image).Value = photo`?

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Also specify `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;`

Answer (score 0):

In your `Update_Customer()` function, you need to provide a value for `photo` as a `Byte()` array.

Here's a paraphrased example from the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4f5s1we0.aspx):

```
Class Test
  Sub Save(connectionString As String, photoFilePath As String)
    Dim photo As Byte() = GetPhoto(photoFilePath)

    Using connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
      Using command As New SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO Employees (Photo) Values (@Photo)", connection)

        command.Parameters.Add("@Photo", SqlDbType.Image, photo.Length).Value = photo
        connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End Using
    End Using
  End Sub



  Public Shared Function GetPhoto(filePath As String) As Byte()
    Dim photo As Byte()

    Using stream As New FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
      Using reader As New BinaryReader(stream)
        photo = reader.ReadBytes(stream.Length)
      End Using
    End Using

    Return photo
  End Function
End Class
```